# Cookies and best practices for implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies, passport.js

Hello fellow developers!

I am pushing on with my food delivery practice website and have now reached the point where I need to implement some cookies. I am building the site using MERN stack.

For my authentication the way I best understand it is to implement passport js on my backend for login in users manually and with google/Facebook auth. However when it comes to creating cookies to store a shopping session eg saving the users cart I'm not sure what the best way to do this would be, do I implement cookies on my frontend with React storing the session locally or should I set it up in my API where everything is stored on the server. This is my first time implementing something like this so any input on best practices would be super helpful! Sorry if the question sounds a bit uninformed I am still a novice!

Comment: Or you could use something like [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to store cart data on the frontend.

Comment: One of the biggest concerns about cookies or localStorage/sessionStorage is XSS attack, and you will need to deal with XSS attack prevention no matter which method you're going to use. My suggestion is to use whatever you like, then start searching how to secure the website.